# Vultures in Germany in the past

Tags: ornithology

I noticed that since the 1970s the [bearded vulture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearded_vulture) , which had disappeared from the Alps due to hunting, has been successfully [reintroduced](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartgeier#Erfolgreiche_Wiederansiedlung_in_den_Alpen). I have searched for the modern habitats of vultures, but it [appears](http://www.geierineuropa.de/cms/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47&Itemid=28) (the wording on the site is a bit imprecise) none occur in Germany beyond the very mountainous regions.

I want to know whether at any point in the past vultures of any species where common across large parts of Germany other than the Alps. I am especially curious about the Middle Ages.

Edit:
This [site](http://www.mittelalterforum.com/index.php/Thread/6628-Geier-und-Schindanger/) in German claims that vultures in Medieval Germany followed sheep herds, eating dead, stillborn and afterbirth of cattle. It mentions, beside the Alps, the upper Danube Valley and the Moselle–Rhine region:

> Bis dahin hatte es vom Mittelalter ausgehend, auch in deutschen Ländern eine einträgliche Zusammenarbeit gegeben. Geier folgten den wandernden Schafherden, beseitigten verendete Alttiere, totgeborene Junge, die Nachgeburt oder die Knochenreste vom Essen der Schäfer. Geier nisteten im Mosel-Rheingebiet, den Alpen und im oberen Donautal.